# Where can I find textstudio download link for windows 32 bit?

Tags: installing

I using latex in overleaf. Where can I find the download link to use on desktop? My system is win 32 bit. And which files for should I install?

Update:
I installed texlive. it moves so slowly. is this normal?
[image]

Comment: https://www.texstudio.org

Comment: and you need a tex system, either texlive or miktex (both work on windows).

Comment: https://miktex.org/download is 64 bit but my sistem is 32 bit

Comment: https://miktex.org/download/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x86/basic-miktex-21.6.exe

Comment: there are more in the "all downloads" tab, and texlive is 32bit anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I added new image.

Comment: @Pitaya88 yeah it usually takes a long time, my TeXworks took 4 or 5 hours to install. It is good though as it installs all of the packages documentation which you can then access.

Comment: I understood thank you

Comment: One last thing, which would you recommend texlive or miktex?